# Sending push notification from android to ios via pubnub

Tags: android, push-notification, pubnub

I'am trying to send push notification with pubnub from android app to ios app. I'am using folowing json as push notificatio message, it works for android but doesn't work for ios:

```
 {
    "pn_gcm": {
        "message": "test message",
        "message_id": 1464707948327,
        "sender_id": "5735b2a2a3c4c3fe01d37600",
        "chat_room": "",
        "message_type": "text",
        "date": 1464707948327,
        "file_url": "",
        "sender_name": "Sorocean Alexei"
    },
    "pn_apns": {
        "aps": {
            "payload": {
                "message": "test message",
                "message_id": 1464707948327,
                "sender_id": "5735b2a2a3c4c3fe01d37600",
                "chat_room": "",
                "message_type": "text",
                "date": 1464707948327,
                "file_url": "",
                "sender_name": "sender name"
            },
            "alert": "sender name: test message",
            "badge": 1,
            "sound": "default"
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Follow the troubleshooting instructions at this link: https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/1127/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues - report back if you still cannot figure out the root cause or solution.

Comment: Did the troubleshooting guide help?

Comment: Thank you, I actually read documentation and find out that for ios push notification there is a class  PnApnsMessage

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary though. JSON payload you provided should work for receiving APNS on iOS devices.

Comment: any updates on this or can we ignore now?

Comment: You can ignore it, I sended push from android to IOS using PnApnsMessage class, thank you!